# How to reduce number of raster bands of a RGB picture?

Tags: raster, remote-sensing, ndvi, rgb, band

For my Master Thesis in Ecology I want to **calculate an NDVI Index.** 
The tricky part is, that I don't have sattelite pictures with bands and so on, **but RGB pictures**. The pictures where taken with a normal digital camera and the NIR pictures were taken by using a filter to block the light from 680 nm onwards. 
The information of the red channel were obtained by extracting this channel out of a normal RGB picture, taken with the same digital camera as the NIR pictures. I stored this extracted channel as a TIF-file.

Now I **loaded these two pictures in QGIS, render type "platted". Starting the raster calculator per picture 3 bands appear.**

**How** can I **reduce these raster channels in raster calculator to only one raster channel per picture?**

Could I combine the information of the 3 bands to one somehow?

Could a simple addition of all three bands per picture help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right you want to merge - stack your bands related to each picture. You can use Raster -> Miscellaneous -> Merge menu for this. You need to check the layer stack in the opening window. 
For this steps and NDVI calculation I've used this tutorial: http://arset.gsfc.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/land/webinars/Advanced_NDVI/ARSET_Advanced_NDVI_Week2_Exercise_Final.pdf which will give you an idea of all the process with Landsat Images. You can apply the same for your picture bands while calculating NDVI.

Comment: great! I will defintiey try this! just a quick idea: simply adding the 3 bands in raster calculator wouldn't be the same, wouldn't it? Or do you know a other option to reduce the number of bands? I even tried "singleband gray", but still three bands.

Answer (score 2):

The Green-Red Vegetation Index is a useful one for ecological purposes.

[image]

From the following publication:

[Motohka, T., Nasahara, K. N., Oguma, H., & Tsuchida, S. (2010). Applicability of green-red vegetation index for remote sensing of vegetation phenology. Remote Sensing, 2(10), 2369-2387.](http://file:///C:/Users/OWNER/Downloads/remotesensing-02-02369.pdf)

> We chose GRVI because the response of GRVI to various ground covers
>   may be simple to interpret. In terms of the balance between green
>   reflectance (wavelengths of around 500–570 nm) and red reflectance
>   (wavelengths of around 620–700 nm), we can find three groups of
>   spectral reflectance patterns for major components of ground cover
>   (Figure 1):
>
> - Green vegetation (conifers, deciduous trees, and grass): ρgreen is    higher than ρred.
> - Soils (brown sand, silt, and dry clay): ρgreen is lower than ρred.
> - Water/snow: ρgreen and ρred are mostly the same.

Vegetation has positive values, soil has negative values and water/snow has near zero.